# Creating a Pandas Dataframe and Assigning Values Based on Another Dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1

ticker     period     calendarDate     updated     dateKey     assetsAverage
WMT        Q          2021-01-01       2021-03-31  2021-04-02  100000000
```

What I want to do is take these values and put them into another dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2

ticker     period     Calendar Date    Updated     Date Key    Assets Average
WMT        Q          2021-01-01       2021-03-31  2021-04-02  100000000
```

I'm using the 2nd dataframe as my output and using my 1st dataframe as temporary storage.

Any suggestions?

I tried doing something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    
        "Ticker":df1["ticker"],
        "Period":df1["period"],
        "Calendar Date":df1["calendarDate"],
        "Updated":df1["updated"],
        "Date Key":df1["dateKey"],
        "Assets Average":df1["assetsAverage"]

    }
)
```

The error message I got was

> TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 6 positional arguments but 112 (I'm actually using more columns, but getting my point across only required a few).
> were given

Edit #1:

This is what I am trying to do now:

```
df2 = df1.copy()

df2 = df2.rename(columns = {
     "ticker":"Ticker", 
     "period":"Period", 
     "calendarDate":"Calendar Date",
     "updated":"Updated",
     "dateKey":"Date Key",
     "assetsAverage":"Assets Average"
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, I got the same error message as before, any suggestions?

Comment: `df.columns = ['ticker',*other new names here*]`, or use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), which returns a new dataframe.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify.

Are you suggesting I do something like
df2 = df1
and then use the rename function on df2?

Comment: Yes, but rather `df2=df1.copy(); df2.columns=...`. Or you can just do `df2 = df1.rename(columns={'calendarDate':'Calendar Date',...})`

Comment: okay, brb, let me play with this. thank you

Comment: still having issues with rename, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Post Edited above

Comment: Actually, your suggestion worked, my error was located somewhere else. Feel free to post as the answer and I'll mark it as so. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.columns = ['ticker', 'period', 'Calendar Date', 'Updated', 'Date Key', 'Assets Average']
```